# What's the point of using "map()" for two elements in perl?

Tags: perl, map-function

I've seen code where there are just two rather static elements to be mapped such as time intervals with start and end dates, yet `map()` is being used rather than explicit code for mapping, e.g.

```perl
{ map { ... } qw(start end) }   # vs.
{ start => ..., end => ... }
```

Which way is preferrable, and why?

The `map` form may be less concise but looks more functional (as in functional programming), so I guess that's why it may be preferred over explicit code and is perhaps more DRY.

However, it looks less legible to me because there is more logic going on behind, and mapping should also be less efficient because it invokes calls a and consists of more atomic operations.

**EDIT**
There is a conflicting goal in programming: KISS (keep it { pick 2 from: small, simple, stupid }). Using `map` slightly complicates code.

Comment: DRY can be very valuable, the author probably disagrees with you on the question of legibility, and any performance difference is negligible *especially* in the case of only two elements. :)

Comment: Also perhaps relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046327/which-features-of-perl-make-it-a-functional-programming-language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a principle of coding known as [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Don't Repeat Yourself.

It asserts that:

> Every piece of knowledge must have a single, unambiguous, authoritative representation within a system.

And that can be interpreted as condensing duplicate typing with (things like) `map`/`for`.

I use idioms like the one you've quoted when I'm trying to expand some text - for example:

```
 my @defs = map { "DEF:$_=$source_file:$_:MAX" } qw ( read write );
```

This generates me some DEF lines for `rrdtool`.

I'm doing it this way, because for *some* cases, I've got considerably longer lists of 'things I want to define' and want to be consistent. (Sometimes I have say, 10 similar lines that differ only by a single word).

But also because:

```
my @defs = ( "DEF:read=$source_file:read:MAX",
             "DEF:write=$source_file:write:MAX" );
```

There's not much in it for two elements, and I'd suggest it's as much a matter of style as anything. However, if you've got more than that, it quickly becomes very beneficial because you can change the *single* line - say you've got a different file location? Want to swap MAX for AVERAGE?

It's also quite shockingly easy to go 'punctuation blind' when looking at a long sequence of similar statements, where someone's typo-ed and added a `,` where it should be `.` or similar.

And ... you probably don't lose a great deal in terms of readability. But will acknowledge that's something of a style point, because whilst `map` is pretty amazing, it *can* make for some rather hard to read code if you're not careful.

Also to specifically address:

> mapping should also be less efficient because it invokes calls a and consists of more atomic operations.

A [wise man](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) once said:

> premature optimization is the root of all evil

Don't think about the efficiency of a statement - look at the legibility/readability. Compilers are pretty clever. Most "obvious" optimisations, they already make for you. Processors are also pretty fast. Your limiting factor in *most* code isn't the amount of CPU cycles you need, it's IO throughput and memory footprint. So don't worry about it - write clear code.

And if there's a performance critical demand on your code, you should be using a code profiler to look at where you gain the most efficiency for your effort at refactoring. You may end up with less clear code in doing so (sometimes) but that's a more clear tradeoff.

Comment: _"premature optimization is the root of all evil"_ - yes, but that does not mean what most think it means. It does not call to ignore obvious, low-hanging optimization fruits but that you should not ponder too much about how to optimize e.g. the system or the architecture prematurely for scenarios which may become obsolete and buy into technological debt.  But right, two elements are simple enough to be insignificant, though I was worried about applying anti-patterns of inefficiency which may later suggest using it where it _does_ matter.

Comment: My point is - worrying about whether `map` is more - or less - efficient than a static assignment counts. Most likely it will never be a problem, so it's not worth worrying about from that pespective.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're not just setting both items to the same constant or something similarly trivial, I would expect the `map` version to be *more* concise.

IMO, the main point in favor of the `map` version is that you know the same process will be used to produce both values.  Not only for the sake of DRY, but also because it eliminates any concern that one might have a subtle change which the other doesn't.

As for the performance concern... If your use case is sufficiently performance-sensitive for any potential difference to matter, then you shouldn't be using Perl in the first place.  Switching to well-written C (not C#, not C++, not Objective C - just plain C) will have a far greater performance impact than micro-optimizing whether you assign two values individually vs. using a loop to set them.  But the odds of your use case being that sensitive are approximately zero anyhow.