# Assigning a variable to a function

Tags: perl, tcl

Couple of questions:

1. Can I assign a variable (regvalue) to a function (read_phy) as below in tcl?

   ```
   $regvalue = read_phy $phy 19
   ```
2. I have the following line in a Perl program. I am trying to figure out what should be the tcl equivalent:

   ```
    while((read_phy($phy, 18) >> 15) ne 0) { usleep(10000); };
   ```

`read_phy` (tcl function) looks like this:

```
proc read_phy {phy register} {

    $value = exec ./read_phy.pl $phy $register
    string trim $value;

    if { $::DEBUG } {
        puts [format "Read PHY %s register %s = 0x%0.8X" $phy $register $value]
    }

    if { $::DEBUG } {
        puts [format "Read PHY %s register %s = 0x%0.8X" $phy $register $value]
    }

    set hex $value

    return ($value);
}
```

Comment: What does read_phy look like (source code)? What have you tried already?

Comment: read_phy (tcl function) looks like this: proc read_phy {phy register} {
 $value = exec ./read_phy.pl $phy $register
 string trim $value;
        if {$::DEBUG} {
           puts [format "Read PHY %s register %s = 0x%0.8X" $phy $register $value]
        }

        if {$::DEBUG} {
           puts [format "Read PHY %s register %s = 0x%0.8X" $phy $register $value]
        }

        set hex $value
 return ($value);
}

Comment: This almost sounds like you're asking a functional programming question, function arities. If not, then I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: That's ok - perl is a functional programming language; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046327/which-features-of-perl-make-it-a-functional-programming-language

Answer (score 3):

1.

```
set regvalue [read_phy $phy 19]
```

2.

```
while { ( [read_phy $phy 18] >> 15) != 0} { after 10 }
```

also the first 2 lines of read_phy should be:

```
set value [exec ./read_phy.pl $phy $register]
set value [string trim $value]
```

- string trim returns a new value, it does not modify its input value.