# How do map and grep work?

Tags: perl

I came across this code in a script, can you please explain what `map` and `grep` does here?

```
open FILE, '<', $file or die "Can't open file $file: $!\n";
my @sets = map {
                  chomp;
                  $_ =~ m/use (\w+)/;
                  $1;
                }
grep /^use/, ( <FILE> );

close FILE;
```

The file pointed by `$file` has:

```
use set_marvel;
use set_caprion;
and so on...
```

Comment: Perl has some great built-in documentation. If you have perldoc installed on your system, you can run [`perldoc -f map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) and [`perldoc -f grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) to see the docs for each function. (I added links to the online version of the docs for your convenience.)

Comment: Thanks, will go through this, map was confusing to me, will read it again (and again) till I understand.

Comment: Essentially, `map` takes an input list and transforms it into an output list. In your example, `map` transforms the list containing `use set_marvel;`, `use set_caprion;` into a list containing `set_marvel`, `set_caprion`.

Comment: By the way, you could also have used: `my @sets = map { /^use (\w+)/ ? $1 : () } <FILE>;` or even just `my @sets = map { /^use (\w+)/g } <FILE>;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite the fact that your question doesn't show any research effort, I'm going to answer it anyway, because it might be helpful for future readers who come across this page.

According to [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html), `map`:

> Evaluates the BLOCK or EXPR for each element of LIST (locally setting
>   `$_` to each element) and returns the list value composed of the results
>   of each such evaluation. In scalar context, returns the total number
>   of elements so generated. Evaluates BLOCK or EXPR in list context, so
>   each element of LIST may produce zero, one, or more elements in the
>   returned value.

The [definition](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) for `grep`, on the other hand:

> Evaluates the BLOCK or EXPR for each element of LIST (locally setting
>   `$_` to each element) and returns the list value consisting of those
>   elements for which the expression evaluated to true. In scalar
>   context, returns the number of times the expression was true.

So they're similar in their input values, their return values, and the fact that they both localize `$_`.

In your specific code, going from right to left:

- `<FILE>` slurps the lines in the file pointed to by the `FILE` filehandle and returns a list
- In the context of `grep`, `/^use/` looks at each line and returns true for the ones that match the regular expression. The return value of `grep`, therefore, is a list of lines that that start with `use`.
- In the BLOCK of your `map` (which is only considering lines that passed the earlier `grep` test):

  - `chomp` removes any trailing string from `$_` that corresponds to the current value of `$/` (i.e., the newline). This is unnecessary, because as you'll see below, `\w` will never match a newline.
  - `$_ =~ m/use (\w+)/` is a regular expression that looks for `use` followed by a space, followed by one or more word characters (`[0-9a-zA-Z_]`) in a capture group. The `$_ =~` is redundant, since the match operator `m//` binds to `$_` by default.
  - `$1` is the first matching capture group from the previous expression. Since it's the last expression in the BLOCK, it bubbles up as the return value for each list item that was evaluated.
- The end result is stored in an array named `@sets`, which should contain `'set_marvel', 'set_caprion', etc.`

Equivalently, your code could be rewritten without `map` and `grep` like this, which may make it easier for you to understand:

```
my @sets;

while (<FILE>) {
    next unless /^use (\w+)/;
    push(@sets, $1);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, and sorry for the dumb question :(

Comment: @Krish Does it at least make sense now? Because if it doesn't, now is the time to ask any follow-up questions.

Comment: I don't think `map` is particularly newbie friendly. But both made considerably more sense when I thought about [functional programming](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31046327/2566198) which was when they started to click.  Both iterate an array (like for) but transform it and return the result.

Answer (score 0):

The `grep` takes the `<FILE>` as input and uses the regular expression `^use` to copy all of the lines that start with `use` into an array that is passed to `map`.

The `map` loops through each array entry and puts each entry in `$_`, then calls `chomp` on `$_` implicitly. Then `$_ =~ m/use (\w+)/;` performs a regular expression on $_ that captures the word after the `use` and puts it into `$1`. Then the `$1` is called to put it in `@set`.